# How to load wordpress by two URL

Tags: wordpress

I need to wordpress from 2 url, my main wp already run in subdomain wp.domain.com but I can't access from domain.com/wp, I try some change in database and .httaccess file, but I can't run it with 2 url

I need can access both of them  :

```
wp.domain.com
domain.com/wp
```

Comment: What are the `some change` you did in Database and .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress doesn't really support this setup. All posts have saved their URL in the database, if you display the site on the secondary URL all links will still point to the primary URL.

Additionally, displaying the same content on different domains (what this is) is usually penalized by search engines, which is something you usually want to avoid.

You can achieve this by configuring the Apache with [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) and [mod_proxy_html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) to proxy all requests on one domain to the other, rewriting the URLs in the process.

The Apache config for this looks like this:

```
ProxyPass /wp/ http://wp.domain.com/
ProxyPassReverse /wp/ http://wp.domain.com/
# to rewrite the URLs in the HTML
ProxyHTMLEnable On
ProxyHTMLExtended On
ProxyHTMLURLMap http://wp.domain.com https://domain.com/wp
```

But I'd recommend to stick to a single URL and configure Apache to redirect all requests on the secondary URL to the primary.

You can do that with a single line in a .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://wp.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```